# Create a sheets using list of values and update values from the table?

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing trouble while developing code for creating multiple sheets and the sheet names are taken from the list in other sheet and then in the created sheets, there are some fields needs to be updated from the table. I mean first created sheet, value to copied from main sheet cell A1 (for example), and next created sheet, value to copied from main sheet cell A2 and goes till end.

I developed code until its successfully copies it but I have no idea how to replace cell values from the table.

I dont knw how much challenging it is but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Sarath

My current code

```
Sub create_sheets()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("input data").Range("C6")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlToRight))

For Each MyCell In MyRange

Sheets("200L_50°C").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet

Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this

```
Set MyRange = Sheets("input data").Range("C6")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlToRight))
```

can be done in one line:

```
Set MyRange = Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(6, 3).End(xlToRight))
```

Also consider more robust version:

```
Set MyRange = Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
```

Having settled this, to create sheets I would rather use `.Add` method:

```
Dim i As Long: i = 1
For Each MyCell in MyRange
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
    'copy the value from main Worksheet - from A1, A2, etc.
    'to A1 in new worksheet - it remains first sheet I assume
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
Next MyCell
```

Also, using `Sheet(1)` is unnecessary, since we don't activate or select any other sheet.

Comment: Hi Michal, 

Using your code I developed further to reach my requirement. thanks for the code that I used it as a start for developing my own.